# How to create Excel XY Scatter Plot in C# with irregular x-axis values

Tags: c#, excel, scatter-plot, excel-charts

I'm trying to create an XY Scatter Plot in Excel in C#, but having a problem.

When I'm in Excel and select the XY Scatter Plot with 2 columns, the program returns an XY Scatter Plot with first column like x-axis and the second one like y-axis. But trying to do in c# with the classic code:

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "B"+(NumbS+1)); //"NumbS" is the number of source values that I want to plot
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter;
```

The program returns an XY Scatter Plot with generic x-axis and 2 y-axis plot (with the first and second columns).

I'm not a good programmer and I'm trying to do everything as simple as I can. How can I plot an XY Scatter with the right x-axis in the easiest way to understand?

Comment: You want an XY Scatter plot that doesn't have *both* an X *and* a Y?  Might be a good idea to check this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot) and get the correct terminology. Also "[mcve]" has some tips.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm brazilian and not so good at english. But my problem is that my program don't return one curve with xy axis as first and second colums. It return two curves, one with the first colum as y-axis and a generic x-axis (first point is 1, second 2, and goes), and other with the second colum as y-axis and a generic x-axis.
But I will read the wikipedia page and the tutorial that you send to never had this problem again.